# Level Calculation with Java

Tags: java, calculator

I need to calculate a Level system for a friend of mine. The problem is that I have no clue how I should do that. He gave me a end point how much experience (31536000) is needed for the max level (44) 
The level should increase in difficulty as higher you are (like degresive progression or logarithmic) I just have no clue how to calculate it backwards or even forward. 
I am not that experience with Java since this is ages for me.

I need every experience needed for each level from 1 to 44 and you reach level 44 by earning 31536000 experience. 
I have test some stuff but I am really not good at that and I know this is a little bit to high for me.

```
public class level{
public static final double base_exp = 1; 
public static final double exp_increase_per_level = 0.40;
public static final int max_level = 44;

    public static int level (double exp){          
            int i = 1;
            double test_exp = base_exp; 
                while (i<max_level) {
                    if (test_exp > exp){
                        return i;
                    }
                    test_exp = test_exp + test_exp * exp_increase_per_level;
                    i++;
                }
            return max_level; 
    }

    public static double level_to_exp (int level) {
        if(level == 1)
            return base_exp;
        else {
            double prev = level_to_exp(level-1);
            return prev + prev * exp_increase_per_level;
        }
    }                

    public static double level_to_total_exp (int level) {
        if(level == 1)
            return base_exp;
        else {
            return level_to_total_exp(level-1) + level_to_exp(level-1) * (1 + exp_increase_per_level);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("to level 1,"+level_to_exp(1)+"exp");
        System.out.println("to level 2,"+level_to_exp(2)+"exp");
        System.out.println("to level 44,"+level_to_exp(44)+"exp");

        System.out.println("Total exp to level 44" +level_to_total_exp(44)+" acuumulated");
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is just basic maths. Your model appears to be:

```
score = base^level
```

So to get the level from the score:

```
log(score) = log(base^level) = level * log(base)

level = log(score) / log(base)
```

To calculate `base`, just substitute in `level=44` and `score=whatever`, and rearrange.

Comment: How do I calculate that in my Situation? How do I insert this?`
I have the base exp starting at 1? 
and the end base value of 31536000?
I dunno the % increasement